# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when adding "-ObjC" in linker flags

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

It is a swift project which was working fine before but I wanted to use Spotify sdk and it requires to add "-ObjC" in other linker flags. But when i add that, I get Apple Mach-O linker flags error.

Although, I created a dummy project to test it and It works fine in my dummy project where I'm using only spotify ios sdk.

In my main project, I'm using Parse,Facebook and now added Spotify.

Any idea what causing that error?